# Knowing that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$ and that $b_n$ is bounded, find $\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n b_n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Knowing that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$ and that $b_n$ is bounded, find $\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n b_n)$

We know that 
$$-M \le b_n \le M$$
Now,I don't know if this step is correct at all, but I would like t simply divide both sides of this equation by n, and therefore get: $$-\frac{M}{n} \le \frac{b_n}{n} \le \frac{M}{n}$$
Now, I take the limit as n approaches infinity: 
$$0 \le \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{b_n}{n} \le 0$$
Therefore,  $\frac{b_n}{n} \rightarrow 0$. 
Now, as we deal with arbitrarily large n-s, I think that any sequence that approaches zero will have the same effect, therefore, I'd like to substitute $1/n$ with $a_n$ and finally get 
$$a_n b_n \rightarrow 0 $$ 
I am however afraid that my reasoning is vague or bogus - I'd really appreciate any hints and / or constructive comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Describe what is your $M$, since $b_n$ is bounded, there exists $M>0$, such that $|b_n|\leq M$, and hence $-M \leq b_n \leq M$.
- Rather than multiplying by $\frac1n$, directly multiply by $a_n$,

$$-Ma_n \leq a_nb_n \leq Ma_n$$

Now take limit, by squeeze theorem.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}-Ma_n \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}a_nb_n \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}Ma_n$$

$$-M\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}a_nb_n \leq M\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$$

$$0 \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}a_nb_n \leq 0$$

hence the conclusion.

- While working with $\frac1n$ might give you an idea of what is going on. We have to justify more why it works for other sequence that converges to zero. For example knowing that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{i^2} < \infty$ doesn't mean the same rule apply for $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{i} $

Answer (score 4):

Note that there exists $M>0$ such that
$$
|a_nb_n|\leq M|a_n|\to0
$$
since $a_n\to 0$. The result follows.

Answer (score 1):

What you do in your second inequality is multiplying by the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$. Try multiplying by $a_n$...